# false gronwall counterexample?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Gronwall's inequality states that if $$f(t) \leq a+\int\limits_{0}^t B(s)f(s)\text{d}s$$ for some constant function $a$, then $$f(t) \leq a \text{ exp}\int\limits_{0}^t B(s) \text{d}s$$.  However, if $f \equiv 1$, $a=0$, $t=1$, and $B \equiv 1$, then $$f(t) \leq a+\int\limits_{0}^t B(s)f(s)\text{d}s \implies 1 \leq 0+\int\limits_0^11 \text{d}s=1$$ is true, but $$f(t) \leq a \text{ exp}\int\limits_{0}^t B(s) \text{d}s \implies 1 \leq 0 \text{ exp }1=0$$ is not.  Would greatly appreciate if someone could point out to me where I am messing up!

Comment: If, say, $t=\frac 12$ then it is not true that $1=f\left(\frac 12\right)≤0+\int_0^{.5}1\,ds=\frac 12$.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware it had to be true for all $t$ on the interval.  Thank you!

Comment: See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) for good statements of Gronwall.

Comment: Another question I have is: what happens if $a=0$ but $B(s)$ is unbounded?  Then, $\text{ exp}\int\limits_{0}^t B(s) \text{d}s$ would be infinitely large, so what would $a \text{ exp}\int\limits_{0}^t B(s) \text{d}s$ be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gronwall's inequality says that if

$$f(t)\leq a +\int_0^t B(s) f(s) ds$$

is true for ALL $t$ then the conclusion holds. That is not the case in your example (let $t=.1$ for example).